# Member object initialization with an object of a class inherited from another class

Tags: c++

I have four different classes which they inherit from each other like in this example:

```
class E {};

class B
{
    B(E e_obj) /* stuff */ {}
    // stuff
};

class D
{   
   E e_obj;     
public:         
    D();
};

class C : public D
{
    C(Parm_t param) /* stuff */ {}
    // stuff
};

class A : public C
{
    B b_obj;
public: 
    A(Parm_t param): C(param), b_obj(/* what to put here */) {}
};
```

In the initialization of `b_obj` in `class A` I need to give it param and `e_obj` from it's parent `class (C)`. How can I do this?

Comment: You can't, that's a private member of class `D`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt and if I can make it public?

Comment: i allowed myself to edit that...

Comment: @Ja_cpp the constructor of `C` can't be private if you want to call it from a child.

Comment: meh rolled back the edit because the answer already quotes the code as is

Comment: @user463035818 no problem thanks.. I'll try when it is private first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `D` is already created at that stage, add an accessor:

```
class D
{
    E e_obj;
public: 
    D();
protected:
    const E& get() const {return e_obj;}
};
```

And use it after:

```
A(Parm_t param): C(param), b_obj(get()) {}
```

Second option, make `e_obj` a protected (not public) member of the class and pass it directly.

There are a few issues as well in the rest of the code, make sure that inheritance is public and constructors are as well.